# ros-fuerte-desktop-full not creating setup.bash, setup.sh, etc

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When installing ros fuerte on Ubuntu precise (sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-desktop-full), it's not giving me the various /opt/ros/fuerte/setup.* files.

When I try building from source (which has difficulties for other reasons), then I do get these tools.  Anyone know why the prebuilt distribution isn't giving me the whole thing?  Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/41010/ros-fuerte-desktop-full-not-creating-setup.bash,-setup.sh,-etc/) by [ssafarik](https://answers.ros.org/users/1687/ssafarik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 306 on 2012-08-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Would you please check the output of the following?

```
echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH
```

This will output the path you have ros installed in. Also, if you could post this, too:

```
cat ~/.bashrc | grep ros
```

For me, I see:

```
allenh1@muri-pc7:~$ cat ~/.bashrc | grep ros
source /opt/ros/fuerte/setup.bash
```

If the above line is not output, you are not properly using your ROS path. To remedy this, run the following:

```
echo "source /opt/ros/fuerte/setup.bash" >> ~/.bashrc && source ~/.bashrc
```

---

I have never heard of the installer failing to create "/opt/ros/fuerte/setup.bash"...

This is an interesting scenario...

Try this:

```
sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove ros-fuerte-*
```

then reinstall. This should remove all things ros.

---

Originally posted by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) with karma: 3055 on 2012-08-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ssafarik](https://answers.ros.org/users/1687/ssafarik/) on 2012-08-09**:
The problem is that there is no setup.bash file (or setup.sh, etc).  I did a "sudo apt-get --reinstall install ros-fuerte-ros-comm" and it gave me the various bin/ros* files, but I still don't get the setup.* files.  I then tried "sudo apt-get --reinstall install ros-fuerte-desktop-full" and no luck

**Comment by [ssafarik](https://answers.ros.org/users/1687/ssafarik/) on 2012-08-09**:
"sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove ros-fuerte-desktop-full" then "sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-desktop-full" still doesn't give me the setup* files.  If they're not part of ros-fuerte-desktop-full, then what are they part of?

**Comment by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) on 2012-08-09**:
Try the edited command.

**Comment by [ssafarik](https://answers.ros.org/users/1687/ssafarik/) on 2012-08-09**:
Yes!  Thanks!  There are apparently some ros-fuerte-* debs that should be dependencies of ros-fuerte-desktop-full.

**Comment by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) on 2012-08-09**:
Please mark this thread as solved so people have a solved thread to reference if this ever happens to others.

**Comment by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) on 2012-08-09**:
Just click the Check mark...